# sqlite выбрать уникальные значения из группы

Tags: sql, sqlite

Допустим есть таблица:

| id | name | company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | masha | yandex |
| 2 | katya | yandex |
| 3 | katya | yandex |
| 4 | lina | mail |
| 5 | alisa | vk |

Мне нужен скрипт которые выведет уникальные значения по группировке по полю `name`, на выходе должны быть уникальные по `name` компании:

| id | name | company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | masha | yandex |
| 2 | katya | yandex |
| 4 | lina | mail |
| 5 | alisa | vk |

Comment: и что там в sqlite отменили `distinct` ?

Comment: distinct не работает с группировкой

Comment: приведите ваш код, ибо из первого примера второй получается с помощью distinct, куда вы тут группировку запихиваете только вам известно

Comment: select DISTINCT(company) выдаст только yandex,mail,vk. Мне нужно на выходе yandex,yandex,mail,vk. Хочу что-то вроде select DISTINCT(company) from table GROUP BY name, именно уникальные компании для человека

Comment: Судя по примеру, группировка должна быть по двум полям: name и company. Как-то у вас противоречиво сформулировано.

Comment: `select distinct name, company`

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся оконной функцией ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT  id,
        name,
        company
FROM
(
    SELECT  id,
            name,
            company,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, company ORDER BY id) AS NUM
    FROM Employees
)
WHERE NUM = 1
```

Если в результате нужно только 2 поля, то ещё проще:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        name,
        company
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

С виду это обычная группировка по двум полям, что-то вроде:

```
SELECT name,company
FROM employees
GROUP by name,company
```

Comment: зачем пихать  группировку туда где distinct нужен?

Comment: @teran Так то да, я просто не помню как у `distinct` нужно в скобки поля брать или нет, или он на все поля сразу действует )

Comment: сразу на все...

Comment: @CrazyElf DISTINCT - это вообще не функция. Какие ещё скобки?

Comment: @Akina ну не люблю я этот ваш sql, хотя местами знаю )